# globally remove the vscode typescript error for explicit "any"

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am migrating my js to ts and I would like to use "any" type as a temporary solution to some of the functions till I finish them all. I got an error on this:

```
const a : any = b
```

I know using "any" is against using ts but as a temporary solution I want to use it without getting an error

is there any configuration in tsconfig.json or vscode to avoid getting an error on explicitly type "any"

my tsconfig.json for the reference:

```json
    /* Type Checking */
    // "strict": true
    "noImplicitAny": false
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use no-explicit-any

```
.eslintrc.cjs
module.exports = {
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off"
  }
};
```